# How to call constructor by string name in groovy

Tags: reflection, groovy, instantiation

We know that we can call a method by string name

```
class Person {
    String profile(){}
}
```

Thus :

```
String method='profile'
new Person()."$method"()
```

## This work!

---

However

```
 Class context='my.package.Person' as Class ;
 new context()
```

Doesn't work

The same for the following attempt :

```
  def map=['person':my.package.Person]
   new map['person']()
```

- Any idea ?

Comment: you call `newInstance()` on the class.  plain java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this the same way, as you would do with java itself (only shorter, 'cause it's groovy!) by using [`newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) and [`newInstance([args...])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-)

```
class Person {
    String name
}

// if you hold the class already (Person is short for Person.getClass())
def p1 = Person.newInstance()
assert p1
assert p1.name==null

def p2 = Person.newInstance(name: "Duffy")
assert p2
assert p2.name=="Duffy"

// if not, load it by name (with package it would be "my.package.Person")
def p3 = Class.forName("Person").newInstance()
assert p3
```

Or with your last example:

```
def map=['person':my.package.Person]
map['person'].newInstance()
map['person'].newInstance(name: "Duffy")
```

Comment: i thought that part was already clear and only the "new" part not.  thanks for enhancing the answer.